# ndb query a model based upon KeyProperty instance

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I have a simple ndb model as follows:

```
class TaskList(ndb.Model):
    title = ndb.StringProperty()
    description = ndb.TextProperty()
    priority = ndb.IntegerProperty()


class UserProfile(ndb.Model):
    user = ndb.UserProperty()
    tasks = ndb.KeyProperty(TaskList)
```

As known, a TaskList object will have an `Entity Kind` `Entity Key` and an `ID`. 
Given an ID say 7. 
I can very well get the object with ID 7 as follows:

```
task = ndb.Key(TaskList, 7).get()
```

But how do i get a user who has the task ID 7?

I tried:

```
tsk = ndb.Key(TaskList, 7).get() 
user = UserProfile.query(UserProfile.tasks  == tsk.key)
```

It works, but is there a better method?

Comment: Is there a reason you are not able to have a user property on the TaskList entity itself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're nearly there - but there's no need to fetch the task, just to use its key property again:

```
task_key = ndb.Key(TaskList, 7)
user = UserProfile.query(UserProfile.tasks == task_key)
```

or equivalently:

```
user = UserProfile.query(UserProfile.tasks == ndb.Key(TaskList, 7))
```